# How to access the array in foreach from outside?

Tags: php, mysql

I have `StartTime` and `EndTime` columns in my Records table they contains time data and I am trying to check if the time written on inputs is between `StartTime` and `EndTime`.

In Records table one record has **StartTime: 09:00** and **EndTime: 12:00** and period of them are **10:00**, **11:00**

So if 10:00 is written on input PHP must echo this: *"This hour already exists!"*

Meanwhile, I check not only the times in one row in the table but also the times in the other recorded rows. I do this with the `while` and `foreach` loop, but I couldn't find how to check the resulting array in my `if` statement correctly therefore my `if` statement doesn't work. How can I accurately check the periods I have created in my `foreach` loop?

**PHP**

```
<?php
    
    $stmt1 = $db->query('SELECT StartTime, EndTime FROM records');
    
    $periods[] = "";
    while($row = $stmt1->fetch()){

        echo '<li>'.$row['StartTime'].' - '.$row['EndTime'].'</li>';

        $start = new DateTime($row['StartTime']);
        $interval = new DateInterval('PT1H');
        $end = new DateTime($row['EndTime']);       
        
        $period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end, DatePeriod::EXCLUDE_START_DATE);

        foreach ($period as $date) {
            $periods[] = $date->format('H:i');  
        }                   
    }               

    echo "<br>";
    
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        
        //Date validations
        $inputTime = new DateTime($_POST['inputTime']);

        if ($inputTime == $periods) {
            echo "This hour already exists!";
        }                       
                                    
    }

?>
```

**HTML Form**

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <p>Time</p>
    <input type="text" id="inputTime" name="inputTime">
    <br>    
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Check">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use simple timestamps, instead of `DateTime` objects.

```
$stmt1 = $db->query('SELECT StartTime, EndTime FROM records');

$periods = [];

while ($row = $stmt1->fetch()){
    echo '<li>'.$row['StartTime'].' - '.$row['EndTime'].'</li>';

    $periods[] = [strtotime($row['StartTime']), strtotime($row['EndTime'])];               
}               

echo "<br>";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    
    //Date validations
    $inputTime = strtotime($_POST['inputTime']);

    $exists = false;

    foreach ($periods as $period) {
        if ($inputTime >= $period[0] && $inputTime <= $period[1]) {
            $exists = true;
            break;
        }
    }
                
    if ($exists) {
        echo "This hour already exists!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @HTMHell . It's really works but how can I exclude first time for example: 09:00, 10:00, 11:00, 12:00 in this period how can I exclude 09:00 from `$periods`.

Comment: @Ulrich just use `>` instead of `>=`